# How to watch service data in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
myApp.directive('myView', ['myService',function($scope) {

  return {
    restrict    : 'C',
    template    : '',
    templateUrl : 'myView.html',
    controller  : function($scope,myService){
                    $scope.items = myService.$data;

                    $scope.$watch('myService.$data' , function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
                     console.log("Watching items ...");
                    });
                  },

  };
}]);
```

I am using the above code, where I want to watch myService.$data which is defined in its service. $watch gets called first time when controller is loaded, Elsewhere in the code I update the service variable $data. This gets reflected in UI as I am using ng-repeat directive and binding with $data.
According to my understating before UI gets updated, this particular watch has to be called again, but it is not. So I assume I am not using watch properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() { return myService.$data; },
    function(...) { /*same*/ }
);
```

**BUT:**

If `$data` is an object you may want to add `,true` to the watch, so that you get notified even if an inner property changes:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() { return myService.$data; },
    function(...) { /*same*/ },
    true
);
```

The declarations in your code are wrong. It should be (only changes shown):

```
myApp.directive('myView', ['myService',function(myService) { // NOT $scope
    ...
    controller: ["$scope", function($scope) { // YOU GET myService FROM THE DIRECTIVE
```